# How to simulate modem speed?

Tags: fiddler

I am trying to configure Fiddler for a download and upload speed of 2 MBPS.
How to change accordingly  CustomRules.js???

```
   if (m_SimulateModem) {
        // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300"; 
        // Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2mb/sec is quite fast-- I trust you understand that for this to work, the network in question must be faster than 2mb down/2mb up?

The closest you can get to approximate this would be as follows:

```
if (m_SimulateModem) {
    oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "2"; 
    oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "2"; 
}
```

Comment: FYI: An old regular modem can only do `56 Kb/s` which is `0.0546 Mb/s` or `0.00683 MB/s`